# Can I populate a Sonata entity export using only getters?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, sonata-admin, sonata

I am building a very simple billing system for a media company using Sonata that includes Payment entities for paying Reporters. The only purpose of a Payment is to be exported to a spreadsheet. We will never edit Payments directly.

I have a bunch of special getters in my Payment entity that don't correspond directly to properties of that entity. Stuff like this:

```
public function getReporterName():string
{
    return
        $this->reporter->getUser()->getFirstname() .
        ' ' .
        $this->reporter->getUser()->getLastname()
        ;
}
```

In my Sonata admin class for this entity, I have told my list view to show `reporterName` as if it is a property. Sonata is smart enough to find and use the getter to retrieve the string I'm looking for. No problem.

The issue comes when I add that pseudo field name into the configureDatagridFilters() method like so:

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('id')
        ->add('paymentComplete')
        ->add('reporterName')
    ;
}
```

Now I get a nasty message when trying to export a spreadsheet, saying this:

> No metadata found for property
> `AppBundle\Entity\Payment::$reporterName`. Please make sure your
> Doctrine mapping is properly configured.

**Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do here? Or will I simply have to suck it up and duplicate some data in the database in order to make my export work?**

If it helps, I'll reiterate here that we **only** need this entity for the purpose of exporting to a spreadsheet. It will never be edited manually.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are stuck using two fields (unless you add a *mapped* field for the *full* name).
You can [use the dot syntax to filter by sub entity properties](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/filter_field_definition.html#filtering-by-sub-entity-properties):

```
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('id')
        ->add('paymentComplete')
        ->add('reporter.user.firstname', null, ['label' => 'Reporter Firstname'])
        ->add('reporter.user.lastname', null, ['label' => 'Reporter Lastname'])
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up working with the dedicated export method to solve this.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SonataAdminBundle/reference/action_export.html